# How to make a dropwizard application ignore all calls until start up is complete

Tags: java, initialization, filtering, dropwizard

I've been asked to setup a way for our dropwizard application to ignore all calls until initialization is complete.  The application we have uses guava cache to duplicate the database; as such, all calls go to it instead of directly to the database.  This cache is built during initialization - as such, I would like to to set up dropwizard's initialize method to serve a wait message until the cache is finished building, instead of attempting to accept any calls.  However, I'm not certain how to go about this.

So far, I do know that any solution would have to go in the initialize method in the main class, as well as have a way to check if the initialization is finished.  I've tried seeing if dropwizard has any hooks that check if initialization is complete, but I have not found anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "serve a wait message"? Do you want the JAX-RS resource to respond in a special way?

Comment: Yes; as of now, when the app is starting, if you go to it before it finishes initialization, the browser will show a "This site can’t be reached" message.  I'm wondering if it would be possible for the endpoints to serve a json that simply says "app starting; please wait", or something similar.  I imagine that this would go in the initialize section of the main application class.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP(S) connector is only started after the [`Application#run(T configuration, Environment environment)`](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.14/dropwizard-core/apidocs/io/dropwizard/Application.html#run-T-io.dropwizard.setup.Environment-) method completed.

You can add a blocking method call or use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to wait for the cache to be populated.

Example:

```
@Override
public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) {
    Cache dbCache = initializeCache(configuration);
    // Custom initializations
    // [...]

    populateCache(dbCache); // Blocks until the cache has been successfully populated
}
```

Alternatively, if you're asynchronously populating the cache, you can use a `CountDownLatch`:

```
@Override
public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) {
    Cache dbCache = initializeCache(configuration);
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // Custom initializations
    // [...]

    asyncPopulateCache(dbCache, countDownLatch);

    countDownLatch.await(); // Blocks until the cache has been successfully populated
}
```